# Why does pymysql hang on a select statement that works fine in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, macos, mysql-workbench, pymysql

In MySQL Workbench I run a query that returns results immediately. When running the same query through pymysql, the program seems to hang on fetching results from the SQL.

I have tried killing additional processes running in MySQL using the KILL  command in MySQL workbench. As I said before, running the query in MySQL workbench returns results immediately.

The query itself is shown below:

```
SELECT at.instrument, at.timestamp, at.account, at.in_out_flag, SUM(at.value) AS total_value
FROM accounting.transactions AS at 
WHERE at.instrument="AAPL"
AND at.account="Ned"
AND at.in_out_flag="OUT"
GROUP BY at.instrument, at.timestamp, at.account, at.in_out_flag
ORDER BY at.timestamp
```

The python code used to execute the query which works nicely with other queries is shown below. My example gets stuck on the cursor.execute line.

```
    def get_list_of_dictionaries_with_select(select_statement):
        conn = get_new_mysql_connection()
        cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute(select_statement)
        return_value = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        return return_value
```

Expected results are that this function (get_list_of_dictionaries_with_select) returns a list of dictionaries representing the results of the query. What actually happens is the program just hangs.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL workbench automatically truncates select statements to 1000 results. This means that if the select statement is returning a large number of results then it could take much longer to run in SQL outside of MySQL workbench. If it is truncated to 1000 results (in workbench) then the query stops running once it finds 1000 of them.